# How to use the ethers.rs smart-contract Multicall to call a function on Polygon and retrieve multiple Vec<Address>

Tags: rust, ethereum

I want to batch calls using Multicall but I do not understand why I keep getting errors. Have been stuck here for some time now. The contract in questions takes a u256 as its only parameters and returns an array of addresses. The contract is located on Polygon, I am 100% sure I am using the right HTTP provider / endpoint on the correct chain. I have called this function single-call many many times already but multicall just won't work for some reason and I fear it might be related to the Multicall internals.

The ABI I input is the ABI for the contract I want to call which should be right.

```
ContractError(
    Revert(
        Bytes(0x),
    ),
),
```

When I change the function name I get:

```
    DecodingError(
        InvalidData,
    ),
)
Error fetching data: Invalid data
```

I have no idea what is going wrong here, I am sure I have the right ABI. This is the full function:

```
pub async fn get_pair_traders_array_two(chain: &str) -> Result<Vec<Result<Token, Bytes>>, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let multicall_address = "0x11ce4B23bD875D7F5C6a31084f55fDe1e9A87507".parse::<Address>()?;
    let contract_address = "CONTRACT_ADDRESS".parse::<Address>()?;

    // Retrieve the endpoint from the NODE_ENDPOINTS_MAP
    let endpoint = match NODE_ENDPOINTS_MAP.get(chain) {
        Some(url) => url,
        None => return Err(Box::try_from(anyhow!("Unsupported chain")).unwrap()),
    };

    // (ugly way to write the ABI inline, you can otherwise read it from a file)
    let abi: Abi = serde_json::from_str(r#"[{"removed too long"}]";

    // connect to the network
    let client = Provider::<Http>::try_from("NODE_ENDPOINT")?;

    // create the contract object. This will be used to construct the calls for multicall
    let client = Arc::new(client);
    let contract = Contract::<Provider<Http>>::new(contract_address, abi, client.clone());

    // Create a new Multicall instance with the specified version
    let mut multicall = Multicall::new(client.clone(), Some(multicall_address)).await?;

    // Create a single call
    let argument = U256::from(0);
    let call = contract.method::<_, Vec<Address>>("symbolArray", argument)?;

    // Add the call to the multicall
    multicall.add_call(call, false);

    // Call the multicall and get the result
    let result = multicall.call().await?;
    Ok(result)
}
```

When I use Polygonscan I can just input 0 and I retrieve an array of H160: Address types. There are little sources on the internet and the documentation of ethers-rs is in a poor state. If somebody knows the solution to my problem please help me out here!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that MulticallV1 is not supported, or at least did not work for me with ethers-rs. Once I used MulticallV3 my code worked immediately.